# how to copy java application TextArea content to a web page text area using java?

Tags: java

I need copy java application TextArea content to a webpage TextArea using the same java application.
where should I start to learn how to do that?

OK here's an example

I want to post a thread in my favorite forum, so I use this URL(http://myfavoriteforum.com/addpost.html) 
a page will appear with text areas for thread title and body.

now instead of writing my post into these text areas 
I go to my java application which contains a jTextArea1 for thread title, jTextArea2 for thread body and a jButton.

I write the title "new movie" and the body "blah...blah..." into the application's text areas Respectively.

the question is how to copy the texts "new movie" and "blah...blah..." from the application's text areas to that forum page text areas by pressing the jButton?

Comment: This is a can or worms, TextAreas store their data in RTF format, which you will first need to convert to HTML.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more.

Comment: From the example, it sounds like you want to have a desktop app which will mimic the GUI of the html form and then populate the HTML page with the values? Is this correct? What might be more useful is make your java desktop app make an HTTP request to the HTML form's submit page with POST method and the body containing the expected POST keys and values?

Comment: yes that's what I'm saying.I need to know where can I learn how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I you mean upoad it to a web site, then you have to learn how to do a web service. You can do that in java using a basic servlet with a `doGet` method, passing the text as a parameter in the url of the web request from your android device to your web server.

It's like the big picture. What you wanna do is interesting and will teach you the essence of web services and backend computing for android apps but it's not trivial.

Regards, 
 Stéphane